# Is GTFS-realtime data in Google Maps Directions API

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I would like to know:

- Is [GTFS-realtime](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/) data available from the Google Maps Directions API?
- If not, are there plans to include GTFS-realtime data in the Google Maps Directions API?

I am a member of a team developing a web application that integrates Google Maps Directions API.  The website provides a "Trip Planner" form in which the user enters From, To, Date, and time data to display trip options into the website. Our  website visitors are specifically interested in Bus transit options.

The integration is working wonderfully. However, the data returned by the Google API does **not** contain GTFS-realtime data. We know that the realtime is known to Google through GTFS feeds provided by the transit provider, and we see the realtime data when doing an identical search via https://www.google.com/maps.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the "Transit Specific Information" that is returned in the Google Maps API DirectionsResult Object (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitInformation). There is no reference to real-time information in this documentation. Even if real-time information is supplied (and I suspect that it is not), there would be no way to distinguish between scheduled and predicted times.